# What does "unisex" mean in the context of mechanical disc brakes?

Tags: disc-brake

I see the term "unisex" used with mechanical disc brakes. What does the term mean in that context?

Comment: I have never seen the term in regards to brakes. My assumption is it will work front or rear.

Comment: Could it be some fancy PC way of saying "small/medium/large" lever based on hand size ?   Totally a guess though.    Could you provide some links to the usage ?

Comment: "Avid Unisex's Mechanical Disc Bike Brake BB7 MTB Graphite Cps (Rotor/Bracket Sold Separately)" and "Sram Unisex Adult Level R/R DIR 800 A1 Brake - Black, N/A"

Comment: Is it perhaps a flawed translation for "left / right interchangeable"?

Comment: Probably kind of like an "agnostic" pump chuck.

Comment: @TIm It is probable that it refers to the levers being interchangeable as you say. I assembled a bike some time ago, using Avid v-brake levers and they where completely symmetrical. I could usa any lever in any side of the handlebar.

Comment: Means they are not pink.

Comment: It's doesn't mean anything. The seller on Amazon isn't one who pays attention to details.
https://www.amazon.com/Avid-Mechanische-Disc-Brake-Bicycle/dp/B01EKOEGPG

Comment: Machine-translated from Chinese? Always a source for funny reading stuff.

Comment: I suspect that they always add a "mens" or "womens" label for things that are gender-marketed (e.g. clothing), and "unisex" for everything else, even though it might make zero sense for products like brakes. A related note: Why do many bike products, including entire bikes, come in a "regular" and a "women" version? Are women not regular people?

Comment: @Erlkoenig that might be a good separate question.  There are reasons.